# ASP.net - Orchard CMS 'hangs' after cooking recipe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm trying to host an Orchard CMS web application. After following the [build and deploy](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop/) instructions and filling out the setup page the application hangs on the message 'This tenant is currently initializing. Please try again later.'.

Two messages are being logged, but I don't have a clue where to start to investigate this problem.

**orchard-recipes-2018.03.22.log**

```
2018-03-22 17:45:38,727 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeManager - Default - INFO Executing recipe 'Default'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:38,773 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Enqueuing recipe step 'Feature'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:38,825 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Enqueuing recipe step 'ContentDefinition'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:38,843 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Enqueuing recipe step 'Settings'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:38,857 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Enqueuing recipe step 'Migration'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:38,873 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Enqueuing recipe step 'Command'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:38,907 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Enqueuing recipe step 'ActivateShell'. [ExecutionId=(null)]
2018-03-22 17:45:39,268 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Dequeuing recipe steps. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
2018-03-22 17:45:39,273 Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue - Default - INFO Dequeuing recipe step 'Feature'. [ExecutionId=cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99]
```

**orchard-error-2018.03.22.log**

```
2018-03-22 17:45:39,574 [6] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - Default - An unexpected exception was caught [http://.../]
Orchard.OrchardCoreException: Unable to make room for file "D:\Inetpub\vhosts\...\httpdocs\App_Data\RecipeQueue\cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99\0" in "App_Data" folder ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Inetpub\vhosts\...\httpdocs\App_Data\RecipeQueue\cd0f58a966e04b4386bf9c03ed507f99\0' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder.MakeDestinationFileNameAvailable(String destinationFileName) in C:\...\Orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\AppData\AppDataFolder.cs:line 80
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder.MakeDestinationFileNameAvailable(String destinationFileName) in C:\...\Orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\AppData\AppDataFolder.cs:line 86
   at Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder.DeleteFile(String path) in C:\...\Orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\AppData\AppDataFolder.cs:line 150
   at Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepQueue.Dequeue(String executionId)
   at Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepExecutor.ExecuteNextStep(String executionId)
   at Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeScheduler.ExecuteWork(String executionId)
   at Orchard.Events.DelegateHelper.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<BuildAction>b__0(Object target, Object[] p) in C:\...\Orchard\src\Orchard\Events\DelegateHelper.cs:line 116
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryInvokeMethod(IEventHandler eventHandler, Type interfaceType, String messageName, String interfaceName, String methodName, IDictionary`2 arguments, IEnumerable& returnValue) in C:\...\Orchard\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 83
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryNotifyHandler(IEventHandler eventHandler, String messageName, String interfaceName, String methodName, IDictionary`2 eventData, IEnumerable& returnValue) in C:\...\Orchard\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had to give the App_Data folder "Full-control" permissions. And not only "Write" as it says in the [docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop/)

Answer (score 0):

Change to "modify". It's sufficient.  Look also [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file/)